# Block diagonal form of elements of SO(n)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonal-matrices

Consider an element $A \in$ SO($n$). I am trying to find its corresponding block diagonal matrix. I prove this by induction on $n$. For $n = 2$, we know that every element is like a rotation matrix with angle $\theta$. I am having trouble for SO(3) and SO(4) for few cases.

each eigenvalue of $A \in$ SO($n$) has modulus 1 as for an eigenvector $v$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$, $|Av| = |\lambda v| = |v|$, and hence $|\lambda| = 1$.

Moreover, If $n$ is odd, then $A$ definitely has 1 as an eigenvalue because of the following argument:

det($I-A$) = det($A$)det($I-A$) = det($A^T$)det($I-A$) = det($A^T-I$) = det($A-I$) = $-$det($I-A$) which implies det($I-A$) = 0.

Suppose $n=3$. We have the cases:

(Case 1) The eigenvalues are (1,1,1).

(Case 2) The eigenvalues are (1,-1,-1).

(Case 3) The eigenvalues are (1,$e^{i\theta}$,$e^{-i\theta}$)

My question is, how to ensure that inspite of 1 being a repeated eigenvalue in case 1, and -1 being a repeated eigenvalue in case 2, how do we get distinct independent eigenvectors of $A$? I have a similar question in SO(4) as well. For instance, if the eigenvalues of an element in SO(4) are -1,-1,1,1, how do we ensure that we obtain four independent eigenvectors?

Comment: Do you know how to compute eigenvectors in the general case? So $A$ any square matrix and $\lambda$ any eigenvalue of $A$, how to compute eigenvectors? The same method can be used here.

Comment: @Bemte But how do we know that $n$ distinct eigenvectors exist for an element in SO($n$)?

Comment: Notably, we could deduce that $A$ is diagonalizable using the spectral theorem for normal matrices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An orthogonal matrix (indeed any normal matrix) is diagonalizable over the complexes by the spectral theorem, so we are guaranteed to have independent eigenvectors for our repeated eigenvalues.

An easy way to see this is to consider the action of $A$ on the orthogonal complement  of the span of its first eigenvector. It restricts to an operator on this subspace, so it has an eigenvector. Repeat the process and you have three orthogonal eigenvectors.

In more detail, suppose we know that $A$ has one eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ (which as you point out, is guaranteed for an $n\times n$ matrix if $n$ is odd). It must have at least one eigenvector $v_1$ for that eigenvalue. Then $A$ preserves the orthogonal complement of $v_1$, so we may consider the action of $A$ restricted to this orthogonal complement, call it $A_1$.

By the way, the fact that $A$ preserves the orthogonal complement of its eigenvector is a fact which you proved yourself in the comments for orthogonal matrices, but it is worth noting perhaps that it is enough to assume $A$ is normal, i.e. it commutes with its adjoint.

In a basis with $v_1$ as first vector, the matrix representation of $A$ will be in block diagonal form, with $\lambda_1$ in the first $1\times 1$ block, and $A_1$ in the $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ block. Determinants play nice with block diagonal matrices, so we have $\det A = \lambda_1\det A_1$ and $\det(A-\lambda)=(\lambda_1-\lambda)\det(A_1-\lambda)$. Consequently the eigenvalues of $A$ are the eigenvalues of $A_1$, but with $\lambda_1$ added in (or increased by one in multiplicity).

With that information in hand, an iterative argument allows us to complete the job. $A$ has an $n$ eigenvalues (possibly repeated), so it has at least an eigenvector $v_1$. Then $A_1$ has $n-1$ eigenvalues, so it has at least an eigenvector $v_2$, which is orthogonal to $v_1$. Then $A_2$ (which is $A$ restricted to the orthogonal complement of $v_1$ and $v_2$), has $n-2$ eigenvalues, so it has at least one eigenvector $v_3$, which is orthogonal to $v_1$ and $v_2$. Iterate this process until you have $n$ orthogonal eigenvectors, and bob's your uncle.

This is a proof of the "if" part of the spectral theorem for finite dimensional operators, which states that an $n\times n$ matrix over the complexes is diagonalizable by orthogonal eigenvectors if and only if it is normal.

Comment: Suppose $v$ is a vector in orthogonal complement of first eigenvector $v_1$. As $AA^T = I$, we can write $0 = <v,v_1> = <Av,Av_1> = <Av,\lambda v_1> $, which implies $<Av, v_1> = 0$. So this means, under the action of $A$, the orthogonal complement of $v_1$ remains preserved. Then, what do we do?

Comment: The list of eigenvalues with multiplicities of $A$ restricted to that orthogonal complement is the same, except with the first eigenvalue deleted. So the new operator has an eigenvalue and an eigenvector.

Comment: How are we saying that this new operator has an eigenvalue and an eigenvector?

Comment: @ChandrahasPiduri every operator over a complex finite dimensional vector space has at least one eigenvalue, and therefore at least one eigenvector.

Comment: @ChandrahasPiduri you stipulated that this operator has 3 eigenvalues. If you pass to the orthogonal complement of one eigenvector, the resulting operator has the remaining two eigenvalues as its eigenvalues. Why? Because the characteristic polynomial is given by a determinant of a block matrix.

Comment: @ziggurism The last statement is not clear. Could you explain it in more details?

Comment: @ChandrahasPiduri you compute eigenvalues by taking the determinant of $A-\lambda$. If you express this in a basis where the first vector is your eigenvector, then the matrix decomposes into block diagonal form with the eigenvalue in the first 1x1 block, and the action of the matrix on the orthogonal complement in the $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ block. So the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$ restricted to the orthogonal complement times $(x-\lambda_1)$. Thus the list of eigenvalues with multiplicity for $A$ is exactly the list of eigenvalues with multiplicity

Comment: (Cont) of $A$ restricted to the orthogonal complement.

Comment: I will edit my answer